# HP MicroServer - HP logo light Orange

Tags: hp, boot, windows-sbs-2008

I just bought one of these HP MicroServer as everyone seems to think they are great for a home lab, I installed SBS 2011 on to the box with no problems.

Suddenly today when I have turned it on the HP logo light on the front of the MicroServer has went Orange, it is usually blue. There is also no output onto the screen.

I have tried all the usual things like re-seating RAM etc

Has anyone came across such a problem?

Comment: This question seems to be a better fit for SuperUser.

Comment: This is really a "call your vendor" issue, particularly as you have a trouble light and you can't determine what's wrong (because your system won't boot). Also "home lab" stuff is specifically off topic on Server Fault - SuperUser would be a better fit, but they'd just tell you what DaveM and I are saying -- Check the obvious, then Call HP...

Answer (score 3):

Have you followed the troubleshooting at [HP Microserver Support](http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c02477794/c02477794.pdf)

Not sure what the "usual things" are so beyond RAM so assure the power supply connections are properly seated. Also check any internal cable connections.  If any hardware has been added, remove it and try booting again.

Assure heatsink is properly seated on the CPU and all fans spin up.

If still under warranty call HP as soon as possible